# Click a link on WebView and open the url in a browser

Tags: react-native, webview

My node version is: 10.6.0
My npm version is: 6.1.8

I am rendering a website under a WebView inside a react native app.

I need to open a URL outside the react native app when I touch a link.

My html file is like below

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" >


            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#fb").click(function() {


            window.postMessage("fbclicked");
        });    
    });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a id="fb" href="fb">Click Here</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

What should i do in my react native App.js to open the link outside of the app.

Need help. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use linking.

```
Linking.openURL(url).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
```

If URL is like http://, it's open the browser. Also if it's mailto: , open your email client . Etc...